# IT Asset Tracking Database - Normalization Issue

Tags: ms-access, database-normalization

this is my first time posting here, but definitely not the first time I have found answers on this site!

I am working on creating an IT asset tracking database for our growing retail chain. We have evaluated several different services, but none of them quite satisfy all our needs - so we are going the custom route. Eventually, we plan on using a SQL database and a web front-end, but for now, Access is the quickest way to get something up and running.

We are looking to track not only assets that are in our stores, but also assets being used by employees. These are the tables that I have currently (that pertain to this issue):

- Assets (model, serial number, etc)
- Locations (list of stores)
- Employees (list of all employees)

In my initial database design, we were just tracking store assets. I had my Assets table and my Stores table, along with an AssetAssignment Table containing the foreign keys from both.

If I want to be able to assign an asset to either a store OR an employee, what would be the best way to go about doing this? Should I create a StoreAssignments table and an EmployeeAssignments table? If I do that, would it make it more complicated when trying to run reports/queries for all assets?

Should I create some sort of Entity table, in which every location and employee has an EntityID. I could then assign the asset to the Entity, rather than directly to an employee or store? Is something like that the right way to go - or the complete opposite direction?

I have played around with Access and SQL databases for many years, but never anything too advanced. I am definitely not a DBA!

Any suggestions you can provide would be much appreciated. I am sure I will have more questions to follow ;)

Comment: Your growing retail chain is using one inexperienced developer to reinvent a wheel, using MS Access? Why? Is it because they don't value asset tracking in the slightest and it's a very low priority? Then it doesn't really matter what your design is, eh :-/

Comment: I think I would use the assignment table with 3 fields - asset, store assignment and employee assignment.  then you can use this with outer joins to the other 3 tables (assets, stores, employees) to get all the necessary information.

Comment: @DonGeorge That sounds good, but why not assignment type, person or store being valid entries.

Comment: @Fionnuala - that works too, but still requires 3 fields for asset, assignment type, assignment.  I prefer to not have two different types of data in one field if I can avoid it, so I wouldn't put both a store ID and an employee ID in the same field, even if the type field distinguishes between them.   For the same reason I wouldn't put stores and employees in the same table if I could avoid it - although I might make a Union query if I really wanted to see both in the same list for some reason.

Comment: @DonGeorge As mentioned in the post, I'm no DBA, but wouldn't having so many blank fields be considered bad design. For the most part, about 95% of our current 1200+ assets are assigned to stores - rather than employees. Which means the vast majority of the records would have the employee field blank. Since I am really going to be the only person accessing the database for the time being (until we move to a better solution), it doesn't really matter much. I'm just trying my best to learn as I go along and follow best practices.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Although I agree about reinventing the wheel, I haven't been able to sway them towards using any existing services. Their main focus is being able to have the information available, when they need it - not how it gets to them. Since I am the one responsible for getting them the information, I am trying to make my life easier. I will pretty much be the only one actually accessing the database - they will just be getting reports from me. If you have an actual helpful response to my question, please feel free to share.

Comment: @Fionnuala Your suggestion makes sense, but I do worry about what DonGeorge mentioned about storing two different kinds of data in the same field. Do you see any problem with that? I believe what you are suggesting is the same as the answer proposed by jason.kaisersmith. Is that right?

Comment: @bps - if you're worried about blanks, you could do 2 tables and Union them when you need to.  One table would be employee assignments, one would be store assignments.  It might be slightly harder to spot unassigned assets, but nothing another query wouldn't be able to fix.  Personally, I wouldn't mind having the blanks there, but my background is from practical work in the field, not academics - so a purist may disagree.  And a blank, meaning "not assigned to an employee", isn't invalid information.

Comment: @DonGeorge The 2 tables approach is what I was considering before coming to StackOverflow. I think your first approach, or the one by Fionnuala, seem like better options though. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @bps I did have an 'actual helpful response', it just doesn't look like one ;-)  - It doesn't matter - do whatever's quickest and easiest. You're literally worrying about database storage waste and performance in a 1200 row text database - that's what, 10MB tops? That's ~0.5 cents of storage space on an SSD and entirely fitting in RAM. Have you spent more than 0.5 cents of your time trying to find 'the best' design? The 'quickest way to get something up and running' is probably a Google spreadsheet and it comes with a web interface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are multiple ways to solve the problem, but a simple one is probably to create a new Table entity where you place the assignments.

[image]

The assignment table is where you add an entry for each assignment, no matter what type it is.

So Asset Id is the foreign Key from the Asset table.
Assignment Type is some why to identify if it is assigned to a Location or employee (this could be simple text, or a number)
Assignment Id is then the foreign key from either Location or Employee

If you will only have have a single asset assigned to one place at a time, then the assignment table can have the asset id as the key.

There are other ways, which might be better or worse but there is no point make it more complex than you need to and over engineering it.  A good solution is simply one that works and meets your needs.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. How do you feel about what @DonGeorge said above though?  "I prefer to not have two different types of data in one field if I can avoid it, so I wouldn't put both a store ID and an employee ID in the same field, even if the type field distinguishes between them."     At the end of the day, I will pretty much be the only one accessing the database. Like you said, as long as it works, that is all that really matters. I'm just trying my best to learn and follow best practices.

Comment: To determine what is the best way for you, why not consider what the queries would be to extract the data and which are easiest for you.  It also depends on where, when and how you join the data.  You can do more work on the DB side or the App side.Each have advantages and disadvantages.  Doing it on the App side has the advantages that if you change your DB later then it might mean less work to update it (depends on your DB of course).

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I will focus more on how I plan to pull the data, before doing more work on structuring the data. Thank you for your advice!